# Open all external links in new window - need help with the code

Tags: php, code

I'm using this code to open all external links in new window (site is based on Wordpress):

```
/* OPEN ALL OUTBOUND LINKS IN NEW TAB */
function autoblank($text) {
$return = str_replace('href=', 'target="_blank" href=', $text);
$return = str_replace('target="_blank"
href="https://example.com',
'href="https://example.com', $return);
$return = str_replace('target="_blank" href="#', 'href="#', $return);
$return = str_replace(' target = "_blank">', '>', $return);
return $return;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'autoblank');
add_filter('comment_text', 'autoblank');
```

Unfortunately it's not perfect because it also opens internal links in new window (only if these are placed in posts or pages - menu items etc. open normally). Does anyone have an idea how to modify this code to not open internal links in new window?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that, Jurgen, but there was an error in the code that I fixed:

```
$('a').each(function() {

    /** Get the current hostname */
    var currentHostname = new RegExp(window.location.host);

    /** Check if the href attribute of the link has a different hostname than the current site */
    if (!currentHostname.test(this.href)) {

        $(this).on('click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            /** Create a URL object for the link */
            var url = new URL(this.href);

            /**
             * Check if the link is an http or https protocol link
             * otherwise just open all other link protocols (tel, mailto)
             */
            if (url.protocol == 'http:' || url.protocol == 'https:') {
                window.open(this.href, '_blank');
            } else {
                window.location.replace(this.href);
            }

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Way to complicated to do this with php in WordPress, I'd advice on doing this on the frontend with a bit of jquery magic. I wrote a tiny jQuery plugin that opens all external links (all links with another domain/host name than the current site) in a new window.

Check out the plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.jold.external-hrefs

To do this manually, without the plugin is pretty simple too:

```
$('a').each(function() {

    /** Get the current hostname */
    var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');

    /** Check if the href attribute of the link has a different hostname than the current site */
    if( !a.test(this.href) ) {

        $(this).on('click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            /** Create an url object for the link */
            url = new URL(this.href);

            /**
             * Check if the links is a http protocol link
             * otherwise just open all other link protocols (tel, mailto)
             */
            if (url.protocol == 'http:' || url.protocol == 'https:') {
                window.open(this.href, '_blank');
            } else {
                window.location.replace(this.href);
            }

        });
    }

}
```